# Simple Queue Data structure. Memory location?

Tags: c++, data-structures, memory-management

This should be operated on stack? Which is what I want, for practice sake. But, I simply cannot wrap my head around using pointers in this code, which I would like to implement, with some help if possible.

I tried ChatGpt but it just doesnt give me a concrete answer.It always tries to allocate the memory to Heap with command "new".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max_size 100

struct Queue {
    int front;
    int back;
    int arr[max_size];
};

Queue createQueue(){
    Queue queue;
    queue.front=-1;
    queue.back=-1;
    return queue;
}


bool isFull(Queue& queue){
    if (queue.back==max_size-1){
        cout<<"\nRed je pun.\n";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

void newElement(Queue& queue, int x){
    if (isFull(queue)){
        isFull(queue);
    }else if (!isFull(queue)){
        queue.back++;
        queue.arr[queue.back]=x;
    }
    
}

void takeElement(Queue& queue,int y){    // here i tried to take off one element from the Queue
    for (int i =0;i<=queue.back;i++){    // but then i understood that it isn't a Queue if you can do that
        if(queue.arr[i]==y){
            cout<<"Your number is: "<<queue.arr[i];
            for(int j=i;j<queue.back;j++){
                queue.arr[j]=queue.arr[j+1];
            }
            queue.back--;
        }
    }
}



void comeToElement(Queue& queue, int x){
    if (queue.back==-1 && queue.front==-1){
        cout<<"\nQueue is empty.\n";
    }else{
        queue.front=0;
        cout<<"\nDeleted part of the queue is: \n";
        for(int i=queue.front;i<=x;i++){
            cout<<queue.arr[i]<<" ";
            queue.front++;
        }
    }
}

void printQueue(Queue queue){
    if (queue.back==-1 and queue.front==-1){
        cout<<"\nRed je prazan.\n";
    }else{
        cout<<"\nYour elements of the queue are:\n";
        for (int i=queue.front;i<=queue.back;i++){
            cout<<queue.arr[i]<<" ";
        }
    }
    
}

void readMeni(){
    cout<<"\n\nPick a command: \n";
    cout<<"==============================\n";
    cout<<"1) Entry of a new element\n";
    cout<<"2) Taking an element from the Queue\n";
    cout<<"3) Print Queue \n";
    cout<<"4) Exit\n";
    cout<<"==============================\n\n\n";
}




int main(){
    int n;
    Queue queue = createQueue();
    while(!(n==4)){
        readMeni();
        cin>>n;
        if(n==1){
            cout<<"\n\nEnter te number which you want in the Queue:\n";
            int x;
            cin>>x;
            newElement(queue,x);
        }else if (n==2){
            cout<<"\n\nEnter the index of the number you want to delete:\n";
            int y;
            cin>>y;
            comeToElement(queue,y);
        }else if (n==3){
            printQueue(queue);
    }
    
}
cout<<"You have EXITED the programme.";
}
```

Thank you for your time!

This code works. But the question is usage of pointers.

Comment: What exactly *is* your question? "Usage of pointers" is not a question, and neither is "This should be operated on stack?" What do you want to use pointers for?

Comment: I would say that you're not ready to be writing a queue if pointers are being actively avoided. This is C-style code on top of that.

Comment: @sweenish The thing im trying to understand is how do I point at the memory adress of the queue and then constantly use that adress as input for the functions.

Comment: In c++ there's usually no need to use c arrays (like `int arr[max_size]`), or raw pointers. In this case you could make `arr` a `std::vector` (or potentially `std::array`). This is assuming you cannot use e.g. `std::queue` (instead of your `Queue`) which gives you what you need out of the box.

Comment: *"Enter the index of the number you want to delete:"*: if that operation is supported, it is not a queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main advantages of using pointers is that it reduces the total amount of stack space that your program takes up.

Take the queue initialization line, for instance:
`Queue queue = createQueue()`. Believe it or not, *this actually creates two objects*. The first is created in the `createQueue` function by the statement `Queue queue;` This is because the default, no-argument constructor is called when you declare an object in this way. Then, the `=` results in the object created by `createQueue` being *copied* to a new variable. Granted, the stack frame for `createQueue` and any variable declared in that function are deallocated when `createQueue` finishes, so you're effectively left with only one `Queue` at the end of the `Queue queue = createQueue()` line.

However, if you were to rewrite your `createQueue` function so that it returns a pointer, and then in your `main` make `queue` a pointer, only one `Queue` ever gets created. For instance:

```
Queue *createQueue() {
    Queue *queue = new Queue();
    queue->front = -1;
    queue->back = -1;
    return queue;
}
...
int main() {
   // ...
   Queue *queue = createQueue();
   // ...
}
```

Now, when you call `createQueue`, a new `Queue` object is created using the default, no-argument constructor again, but this time that object goes on the heap. What goes on the stack is a pointer that holds the address of the `Queue` object. Back in `main`, that pointer gets assigned to the `queue` variable, and you can access its members just as easily as you could when the `queue` wasn't a pointer.

To get a little more technical (and maybe you don't really care about this bit, but I think it's important), assuming an `int` consumes four bytes of memory on your system, then one `Queue` would take up 408 bytes of memory. That means that, without pointers, 816 bytes are used on the stack for both `Queue`s in `Queue queue = createQueue()`. With pointers, assuming pointers require eight bytes of memory, you'd have 408 bytes on the heap, and the `Queue*` would only take up eight on the stack.

Object copying also happens whenever you pass a variable by value, as you're doing in your `printQueue` function (i.e. `printQueue(Queue queue)`). So, the `queue` object winds up being copied, thus using up an extra 408 bytes of stack space you wouldn't otherwise need to use were you to use pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes I do care for the detail. 

I will go through this in depth. 

But the first thing that comes to mind is -- that with the "new" operator am I not transfering the location to Heap and I'm really trying to keep it on Stack.

Comment: @harrnui The `new` operator means that you're allocating heap space. But, why are you trying to keep things on the stack? There are some advantages to not using the stack, but ultimately, I think you'll find that learning how to use pointers effectively will improve your programs tenfold.

Comment: It is for training , why I want to keep it on Stack. 

Beacuse after learning the theory a little bit -- I figured this should be doable. But I have not manged it .

Comment: @harrnui By "theory", you're referring to using pointers, yes? If so, the only way to become better at using and understanding them is to write programs with them.  Your `Queue` structure is a simple enough to convert to a pointer-based structure. The only things you'd really need to change are how you initialize a queue, how you access its members, and how you pass it around your functions. There's absolutely nothing wrong with posting incorrect/incomplete code with the intent of learning from the responses you get; that's one of the reasons SO exists.

Comment: Yes pointers too. 

It really is my last resort to go to SO.

I'll be better when I come next time around !

Answer (score 1):

You surely can use the stack, although that is not the common practice.

Some comments:

- Your functions to access the queue look like how one would do it in C, but in C++ these are candidates for *methods* of the `Queue` class, including a constructor.
- When the user wants to take a value from the queue, they should not have to enter an index. With a queue you can only pop a value from the front.
- It is not user-friendly from them to have to make a menu choice whenever they want to see the queue. Just display the queue in each iteration of your loop.
- Your logic for detecting when the queue is full is wrong. When `front` has moved up, there is free space in the array at the start of the array, and so the queue is not full when `back` has reached the highest index. It can *wrap around* and use some space at the start of the array. All this is easier when you have a queue member for its `size` and have `back` dynamically calculated from the combination of `start` and `size`. The queue is full when `size == max_size`.
- The basic functions for the queue should not print. Printing is a task for the main program. `comeToElement` is not a function that is typical for a queue.
- `takeElement` cannot change the caller's value of `y`. In this case it would make sense for this function to *return* the value it pulled from the queue.

Here is an implementation with these remarks taken into account and some others too:

```
#include <iostream>

#define max_size 100

class Queue { // Define as class
private: // Don't allow main code to access these members directly:
    int front;
    int size; // Define size instead of back -- it makes wrapping around easier
    int arr[max_size];

public:
    Queue() { // This replaces `createQueue`
        front = 0;
        size = 0;
    }

    bool isFull() {
        return size == max_size;
    }

    bool isEmpty() { // Add this method too -- it mirrors `isFull`
        return size == 0;
    }
    
    bool enqueue(int x) {
        if (isFull()) {
            return false;
        }
        int back = (front + size) % max_size;
        arr[back] = x;
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    int dequeue() { // Return the value
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return -1; // Return some default value.
        }
        size--;
        return arr[front++];
    }

    std::string toString() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return "(empty)";
        } else {
            std::string s = "(";
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                s += std::to_string(arr[(front + i) % max_size]) + " ";
            }
            s[s.length() - 1] = ')';
            return s;
        }
    }
};

int getUserInput() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "==============================\n";
    std::cout << "1) Add a new element to the queue\n";
    std::cout << "2) Take an element from the queue\n";
    std::cout << "3) Exit\n";
    std::cout << "==============================\n";
    std::cout << "Pick a command: ";
    std::cin >> n; // Moved here
    return n;
}

int main() {
    Queue queue;

    while (true) {
        // Always print queue:
        std::cout << "Current state of the queue: " << queue.toString() << "\n\n";
        int n = getUserInput(); // Have the function return the user's choice
        if (n == 3) break;
        if (n == 1) {
            std::cout << "Enter te number which you want to enqueue: ";
            std::cin >> n;
            queue.enqueue(n);
        } else if (n == 2) {
            // Nothing should be asked from the user here... 
            n = queue.dequeue();
            std::cout << "The value " << n << " was dequeued.\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "You have exited the program.\n";
}
```